# Converting Dataframe into List and inputting the function

Tags: r

I have a dataset with different receipts, items and its value:

```
library(arules)

library(VennDiagram)

Data <- data.frame(
  Receipt_ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6),
  item = c('a','b','c','k','a','b','d','k','a','k','c','q','k',                    'a','b','a','a', 'b', 'c'
  )
  ,
  value = c(2,3,2,4,2,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,4
  )
)
```

And I created a market basket, with some output like below:

```
rules <- data.frame(
  Target = c("a","a","b"),
  item1 = c("b","b","k"  )
  ,
  item2 = c("k","",""),
  lift = c(1,2,3),
  confidence = c(0.08,0.45,0.1)
  )
)
```

I created a function which will take the Vector of items as input(Combination of Target, item1, item2 in vector form)

```
findvalue <- function (vectormb) {
  keyvalue <- Data[Data$item %in% vectormb, ]
  keyvaluetran <- sapply(vectormb,function(x){
    ret <- unique (keyvalue$Receipt_ID[keyvalue$item==x])
  })

  #reducetran <- calculate.overlap(keyvaluetran)
  reducetran1 <- Reduce(intersect,keyvaluetran)
  totalsales <- sum (keyvalue$value[keyvalue$Receipt_ID %in% reducetran1])
  return(totalsales)

}
```

And I comverted the Dataframe to List

```
    createlist <- function(data){
      subset <- data.frame(data$Target,data$item1,data$item2)
      listdata <- apply(subset,1,
            function(x){
              ret<-list( x[1:ncol(subset)])
              names(ret)<-as.character(x[1])
              return(ret)
            })

listdata <- createlist(rules)
```

List data converts the dataframe to vector.

My question is how can I pass the Listdata Output to the function findvalue.

I tried couple of things:

1. findvalue(c("a","b","k")) is giving proper value as 23.
2. When I tried findvalue(listdata[1]), this is not giving any value.

What mistake I did. Listdata should be sent to findvalue in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `createlist()` function has no return value - hence it returns nothing for you. Here is what I would suggest:

```
createlist <- function(data) {
  subset <- data.frame(data$Target,data$item1,data$item2)
  apply(subset,1,
        function(x){
          ret<-list( x[1:ncol(subset)])
          names(ret)<-as.character(x[1])
          return(ret)
        })
}

listdata <- createlist(rules)
```

This will create your `listdata` variable properly.
Then, in order to run `findvalue()` on it, the way the function is currently written, you need to pass on a vector, and not a list. Thus:

```
> class(listdata[1])
[1] "list"
> findvalue(unlist(listdata[1]))
[1] 23
```